# I want to change the torch nn.Conv2D to the tensorflow 2.0 Conv2D

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

```
# Localization prediction convolutions (predict offsets w.r.t prior-boxes)
        self.loc_conv4_3 = nn.Conv2d(512, n_boxes['conv4_3'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1) # 38 x 38 x 512
        self.loc_conv7 = nn.Conv2d(1024, n_boxes['conv7'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1)# 19 x 19 x 1024
        self.loc_conv8_2 = nn.Conv2d(512, n_boxes['conv8_2'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1)# 10 x 10 x 512
        self.loc_conv9_2 = nn.Conv2d(256, n_boxes['conv9_2'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1) # 5 x 5 x 256
        self.loc_conv10_2 = nn.Conv2d(256, n_boxes['conv10_2'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1)# 3 x 3 x 256
        self.loc_conv11_2 = nn.Conv2d(256, n_boxes['conv11_2'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1)# 1 x 1 x 256
```

here we have the #38,x 38 x 512 in pytorch 
I want to change this convolution to the tensorflow > 2.0

what I tried is here

```
  # Localization prediction convolution
        self.loc_conv4_3 = Conv2D(512, self.n_boxes['conv4_3'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.loc_conv7 = Conv2D(1024, self.n_boxes['conv7'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.loc_conv8_2 = Conv2D(512, self.n_boxes['conv8_2'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.loc_conv9_2 = Conv2D(256, self.n_boxes['conv9_2'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.loc_conv10_2 = Conv2D(256, self.n_boxes['conv10_2'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.loc_conv11_2 = Conv2D(256, self.n_boxes['conv11_2'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
```

but get the following error

> ```
> self.pred_convs = PredictionConvolutions(n_classes)   File "/home/jake/Gits/ssd_tensorflow/model.py", line 142, in __init__
> self.loc_conv4_3 = Conv2D(512, self.n_boxes['conv4_3'] * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1) TypeError: __init__() got multiple values
> ```
>
> for argument 'kernel_size'

Comment: what is `self.n_boxes['conv4_3'] * 4`? In tensorflow, you don't need to specify the in_features and out_features like in pytorch. i'm assuming that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: self.loc_conv4_3 = Conv2D(512,  kernel_size=3, padding=1) ?

Comment: that should work in most cases, but i have to say i don't really understand your questions